# Is there a way to turn off number of nested rows when row grouping?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

When using the row grouping feature of AG Grid, the group columns display a number in parentheses to indicate the number of nested rows within that group.

[In this example of row grouping,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2ElM.png) the data is being grouped by different countries, with the numbers in question displayed after the country names. E.g. the number 1109 after United States. Is there any way I can turn this off or hide these numbers?

Comment: Why would you want to hide the occurrences? They are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to configure your `<AgGridReact>` component with the following properties. Without the `groupUseEntireRow` property set to `true`, the `suppressCount` will be ignored.

```
<AgGridReact
  groupRowRendererParams={{ suppressCount: true }}
  groupUseEntireRow
>
```

Or you can bind a `groupRowInnerRenderer` to the the `frameworkComponents` property for a custom renderer.

```
<AgGridReact
  frameworkComponents={{ groupRowInnerRenderer: GroupRowInnerRenderer }}
  groupRowRendererParams={{
    innerRenderer: 'groupRowInnerRenderer',
    suppressCount: true,
  }}
  groupUseEntireRow
>
```

Here is a slimmed-down version of the [Full Width Groups Rendering](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/grouping/#example-full-width-groups-rendering) renderer.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const GroupRowInnerRenderer = (props) => {
  const { api, node: { key } } = props;
  const [groupKey, setGroupKey] = useState(key);

  const onDataChanged = () => {
    const { node: key } = props;
    setGroupKey(key);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    api.addEventListener('cellValueChanged', onDataChanged);
    api.addEventListener('filterChanged', onDataChanged);

    return () => {
      api.removeEventListener('cellValueChanged', onDataChanged);
      api.removeEventListener('filterChanged', onDataChanged);
    };
  }, [api]);

  
  return (
    <div className="groupTitle">
      {groupKey}
    </div>
  );
};

export default GroupRowInnerRenderer;
```